# How animate stacking divs in javascript/css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Say I have 2 `div`s with the same CSS class that are stacked on top of each other:

```
div {
  width:100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

How do I make it so that when I click a button at the top of the page, a new `div` is created from off the screen at the bottom and moves upwards stopping where the 2nd `div` is.. When the button is clicked again, a 4th `div` moves in from the bottom of the screen and stops where the 3rd `div` is... etc creating a "stacked" divs effect?

I know about `position:fixed` and adjusting values for `top`, but I am not sure how to dynamically calculate where to stop the animation to achieve this effect.

Comment: You should use `position:absolute`, so that when you scroll the page, the `div` won't move.

Comment: @Derek may be you mean `position: fixed;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the last added div as a jQuery object, you can calculate the y-position of it's bottom by

```
 var divTop = $(lastDiv).offset().top;
 var divBottom = divTop + $(lastDiv).outerHeight();
```

Then you would animate the top value of your new div to equal `divBottom`.